# Cannot read property 'steps' of undefined at EventEmitter.testStepFinished (node_modules\protractor-cucumber-framework\lib\resultsCapturer.js:80:22)

Tags: typescript, protractor

I am able to execute the before function, but at the end it is throwing:

> Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'steps' of undefined.

```
import { defineSupportCode } from 'cucumber';
import { testDataHolder } from '../../testResources/testDataHolder';
defineSupportCode(function({ Before }) {
    const xls : testDataHolder = new testDataHolder();

    Before({tags:"@TestFeature"}, function () {
        console.log("Executing @TestFeature");
        xls.readUserData();
        xls.readTestData("GU2139");
        console.log("Executed @TestFeature");
    });
});
```

I am using: Protractor 4.0.14, typescript 2.4.2 and cucumber 3.0.0.

//testDataHolder.ts

```
import {ExcelUtility} from '../Utilities/ExcelUtility';
export class testDataHolder {
public xlUtil: ExcelUtility = new ExcelUtility();
public testData: any;
public userData: any;
constructor () {
this.testData = null;
this.userData = null;
}

readTestData (sheetName) {
let dataSheet = this.xlUtil.readDataSheet(sheetName);
this.testData = dataSheet;
}

readUserData() {
let users = this.xlUtil.readUserSheet();
this.userData = users;
}
}
```

//ExcelUtility.ts

```
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
export class ExcelUtility {

readUserSheet () {
let wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.readFile("GUITestData.xlsx");
let wbs: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets["Traders"];
var UserArray = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(wbs);
if(UserArray.length > 0) {
  return UserArray;
}else{
  throw "Empty User data sheet!!";
}
}

readDataSheet (sheetName) {
let wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.readFile("GUITestData.xlsx");
let wbs: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[sheetName];
//var ExpectedData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(WorkSheet);
var ExpectedData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(wbs);
if(ExpectedData.length > 0){
  return ExpectedData;
}else{
  throw "Data sheet for "+ sheetName+" is empty!";
}
```

}
}

Comment: Please provide full code of your methods (`xls.readUserData()` and `xls.readTestData()` else we can't help you much but the error is pretty straightforward, you have an undefined object on which you're looking for `steps` property.

Comment: These aren't readable, please edit your question with properly formatted code.

Comment: i have placed the complete methods i m using